# Erlang vm loads without hipe support on ubuntu vm

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, virtualbox, hipe, kerl

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server on a Virtualbox vm. After that I wanted to install erlang using the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DESTDIR="$HOME/workspace/erlang"
ACTIVATE=". $DESTDIR/activate"
KERL_CONFIGURE_DISABLE_APPLICATIONS="odbc"
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--enable-dirty-schedulers --enable-hipe --with-openssl" 

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerl/kerl/master/kerl
chmod a+x kerl
./kerl update releases
mkdir -p "$DESTDIR"
./kerl build 19.0 erlang.19.0.dirty_sched.ssl
./kerl install erlang.19.0.dirty_sched.ssl "$DESTDIR"
echo "$ACTIVATE" >> "$HOME/.bashrc"
"$ACTIVATE"
```

The script works fine, but even though I explicitly enabled hipe the erlang vm boots up without hipe support:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

I tried to `./configure` & `make` otp manually in the kerl build directory, and it seems hipe support is enabled fine. However, the same problem persists with the manual build:

```
~/.kerl/builds/erlang.19.0.dirty_sched.ssl/otp_src_19.0/bin$ ./erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.0  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

I use the same setup on a physical Ubuntu host and there hipe works seamlessly so I'm starting to wonder if this has to do with the fact that this machine is virtualized: are there any cpu features that hipe requires? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have GNU `m4` installed? Try running `sudo apt-get install m4` and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem! Can you describe what hipe needs m4 for? Add an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Btw. https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Installation doesn't list m4 as a dependency, but then again it seems to be outdated anyways. One should rather look at https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As listed in [Erlang/OTP Build and Install](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html) page, there are some [Required Utilities](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#id61921) needed for the installation. As mentioned their:

> These are the tools you need in order to unpack and build Erlang/OTP.
>   . . .
>
> - GNU `m4` -- If HiPE (native code) support is enabled.

So you would need to install GNU `m4` in order to have HiPE support enabled.
Install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install m4
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my [installation script](https://gist.github.com/tnull/2f4506f274198e5bb1f23b61a7456b8e)